# Updating JDK1.7.0_05 to JDK1.7.0_25

Tags: java, updates

C:\Program Files\Java has 4 folders, jdk1.6.0_21, jdk1.7.0_05, jdk1.7.0_25 and jre7

For some reason I also have C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7

I have checked;

```
java -version
```

and its using 1.7.0_05

I've also checked in eclipse

```
public class JavaVersion 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtim e.version"));
}
}
```

And I get: 1.7.0_05-b05

User Var set to: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre Name: JAVA_HOME`

System Var set to: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin; var name: JAVA_HOME`

Can anyone see anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: replace the JVM on your PATH with the newer version

Comment: try `which java` on linux or `where java.exe` on windows to see where the executable you are running is located

Comment: Tracing the path gives me C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin

Comment: So I downloaded the new version to try that out, I can use Path=%Path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin" in cmd and that actually works it reflects as jdk1.7.0_51 however using those path settings in Environmental variables and then restarting it will go back to jdk1.7.0_21

Answer (score 0):

Check your path settings....
Just do the following....

Go to command prompt

Type Path=%Path%; give here your "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin" path; press enter

Now try java -version

You will get 1.7.0_25

Then you can add the path in path environment variable.

Even after you are getting 1.7.0_05 then check your path entry, if there is jdk bin entry for 1.7.0_05 before the 1.7.0_25.

Comment: Isn't using that in the command-line only temporary? Besides typing the path Path=%Path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin" then checking version still gives me 1.7.0_05. Changing the path via the command line is the same as doing it in the Environmental variables isn't it?

Comment: Yes both are same. It was suggestion to check, before make changes in path environment variable.

Comment: Yer it works well at least with the latest package I tried 1.7.0_51... Doing that however in the Environmental variables changes nothing...